# ¿Como hacer ALTER TABLE en SQL Server 2008 R2 para agregar IDENTITY(1,1)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Como hago para Agregar **IDENTITY(1,1)** en Tabla ***Consulta Nº1***, en la Columna **UserUID** cuya Tabla tiene registros de UserUID Pre-existentes **sin** tener que adulterar osea (Re-crear la tabla) o Borrar los datos de la columna UserUID pre-existentes?

**IMPORTANTE:Ya se que es autoincrementable y unica al menos creo eso entendi por (IDENTITY(1,1))**

**CONSULTA Nº1**

```
USE [PS_UserData]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Users_Master]    Script Date: 07/21/2018 12:43:54 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users_Master](
        [RowID] [int] NULL,
        [UserUID] [int] NULL,
        [UserID] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
        [Pw] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
        [JoinDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
        [Admin] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [AdminLevel] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [UseQueue] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [Status] [smallint] NOT NULL,
        [Leave] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [LeaveDate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
        [UserType] [char](1) NOT NULL,
        [UserIp] [varchar](15) NULL,
        [ModiIp] [varchar](15) NULL,
        [ModiDate] [datetime] NULL,
        [Point] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Enpassword] [char](32) NULL,
        [Birth] [varchar](8) NULL,
        [email] [varchar](max) NULL,
        [Activation] [varchar](max) NULL,
        [SocioRock] [varchar](max) NULL,
        [nacimiento] [varchar](max) NULL,
        [profile_img] [varchar](max) NULL,
        [nombre.] [varchar](max) NULL,
        [apellido.] [varchar](max) NULL,
        [firmas] [varchar](max) NULL,
        [pais] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [mes] [int] NULL,
        [dia] [int] NULL,
        [anio] [int] NULL,
        [nombre] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [apellido] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [MotivoBan] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [GS] [int] NULL,
        [Contador] [tinyint] NULL,
        [Activo] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [FechaDuper] [datetime] NULL,
        [FinBan] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [Verifi] [int] NULL,
        [Protector] [varchar](40) NULL,
        [Staff] [int] NULL,
        [DEV] [int] NULL,
        [Email_viejo] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [UserID_Viejo] [varchar](255) NULL,
        [Point2] [int] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO
```

Comment: No se entiende bien qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente, si dar a esa columna la propiedad auto-incremental, y/o llave primaria o que... Y deberías decir como está la tabla actualmente, si tiene otra llave primaria, etc.

Comment: creo que son ambas  de las dos auto incrementar te la podre de otra manera

Comment: Por favor sé más claro en tu planteamiento. ¿Cuántas tablas son, una, dos, tres? ¿Cómo se llaman?  Ni siquiera eso es claro para empezar. Y di lo que quieres hacer con cada una de esas tablas/columnas, llamando las cosas por su nombre. La pregunta es totalmente confusa.

Comment: ok amigo explico necesito convertir el UserUID en una columna UNICA que se auto-incremente y sea a su vez UNICA

Comment: Bien, con `IDENTITY` logras el auto-increment, en cuanto a la unicidad se puede lograr de dos maneras: haciendo la columna llave primaria > `ALTER TABLE dbo.TuTabla  ADD UserUID INT IDENTITY
       CONSTRAINT PK_TuTabla PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED;` o haciendo la columna única: `ALTER TABLE TuTabla ADD CONSTRAINT AK_TuTabla_ UserUID UNIQUE(UserUID);` No es lo mismo una llave primaria que una restricción de unicidad. Hay discusiones sobre cuándo usar una u otra, si es importante para ti conviene que leas al respecto.

Comment: A ver si se entiende mejor amigo intente las dos consultas que me enviastes y ninguna me funciono igualmente me gustaria y me seria un placer calificar su respuesta Cada dia uno aprende algo nuevo Gracias amigo.

Comment: Y disculpa ¿ADD no es para agregar Columnas en Tablas? ¿no para modificar columnas? disculpa mi ignorancia.

Answer (score 1):

una columna no se puede hacer identity despues de ser creada, vas a tener que crear una nueva columna

```
 Alter Table Names
 Add Id_new Int Identity(1, 1)
 Go
```

Esto generara los identities, pero por desgracia puede que no coincidan con los valores que antes tenias.

si quieres que los identitys conicidan con otra columna vas a tener que reinsertar todos los registros con la identity que les correspondan.

para eso necesitas habilitar identity insert

```
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable ON
 GO
```

y despues insertar cada registro(tomando en cuenta el identity) y después borrar el viejo registro.

y finalmente deshabilitar identity insert

```
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable OFF
```

una vez que los insertes tendrás que regenerar la semilla (el punto donde se empezaran a generar los identities nuevamente

```
 DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Emp', RESEED, 1)
```

comentario final... todo esto es mas fácil de realizar si creas una nueva tabla